# is data a reserved keyword in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

The code below doesn't work if I use `data in lst`, it works, if I **replace** `data` with `x`, so is data a reserved keyword in AngularJS and why?

```html
<script src="http://ajadata.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='app1'>
  <div id='Grocery' ng-controller='Grocery'>
    <h3>Grocery List</h3>
    <div ng-repeat='data in lst'>
      <h4>{{data.item}}</h4>
    </div>
    <br>

    <p> enter item:
      <input type="text" ng-model='addItem' />
    </p>
    <button ng-click='addTolist(addItem)'>Add to list</button>
    <button ng-click='addTolist(addItem)'>Add to list</button>
    <h2>{{NoItemError}}</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Grocery -->
  <script>
    var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);
    app1.controller('Grocery', function($scope) {
      $scope.lst = [{
          item: 'banana',
          needed: false
        },
        {
          item: 'apple',
          needed: false
        },
        {
          item: 'milk',
          needed: false
        },
        {
          item: 'tomato',
          needed: false
        },
        {
          item: 'juice',
          needed: false
        }
      ]
      $scope.addTolist = function(addItem) {
        if (!(addItem === undefined || addItem === '')) {
          $scope.lst.push({
            item: addItem,
            needed: false
          });
          $scope.NoItemError = '';
        } else {
          $scope.NoItemError = 'Please enter an item';
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what exactly doesn't work? You have an incorrect JS URL in the `script` tag. And to clarify, `data` is not a reserved keyword in AngularJS. Can you create a fiddle which can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Your code is working fine check [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LE4imuhJwdVCYM3h14MB?p=preview).

Comment: @KaustubhKhare weird because on my local machine (without server) it doesn't with data but with x name

Comment: @31piy added a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While replacing text with another, you broke your CDN URL for the AngularJS script.
It became `http://ajadata.googleapis.com`

Change it to `http://ajax.googleapis.com`

Here is a full script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

---

And here is a working example of your code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='app1'>
  <div id='Grocery' ng-controller='Grocery'>
    <h3>Grocery List</h3>
    <div ng-repeat='data in lst'>
      <h4>{{data.item}}</h4>
    </div>
    <br>

    <p> enter item:
      <input type="text" ng-model='addItem' />
    </p>
    <button ng-click='addTolist(addItem)'>Add to list</button>
    <button ng-click='addTolist(addItem)'>Add to list</button>
    <h2>{{NoItemError}}</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Grocery -->
  <script>
    var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);
    app1.controller('Grocery', function($scope) {
      $scope.lst = [{
          item: 'banana',
          needed: false
        },
        {
          item: 'apple',
          needed: false
        },
        {
          item: 'milk',
          needed: false
        },
        {
          item: 'tomato',
          needed: false
        },
        {
          item: 'juice',
          needed: false
        }
      ]
      $scope.addTolist = function(addItem) {
        if (!(addItem === undefined || addItem === '')) {
          $scope.lst.push({
            item: addItem,
            needed: false
          });
          $scope.NoItemError = '';
        } else {
          $scope.NoItemError = 'Please enter an item';
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

---

Most reserved words in AngularJS start with `$`, for example `$index` or `$id`, etc.